Facebook Python SDK update AdSet daily budget
I am trying to update the daily budget of a Facebook AdSet via Python SDK but with no results.
The code runs without exceptions but the daily budget is not updated.
This is the code:
    try:
        ad_set = AdSet("ADSET_ID")
        ad_set.update({
            AdSet.Field.daily_budget: '700'
        })
        print("The AdSet budget has been updated")
    except Exception as error:
        print("[ERROR] The budget for the AdSet was not updated")
        print(error)

What am I doing wrong?

It's important to check and share what API version you are using.
On version 19, I perform a similar operation using the method api_update, instead of update. Also, note that daily_budget should be an integer and not a string. So your code would be something like:
ad_set.api_update({
        AdSet.Field.daily_budget: 700
    })

